# How to submit a form from home domain to sub domain?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I want to submit a Form from home page to sub domain page.
Here is my code

**html - home page (main domain)**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="txtName" id="txtName" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="txtEmail" id="txtEmail" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit"  value="Submit" type="button"></td>
    </tr>             
</table> 

<form id="getDetails" method="post" action="http://customers.liyyas.com/">
    <input type="hidden" name="act" value="Users" />
    <input type="hidden" name="hdnName" id="hdnName" />
    <input type="hidden" name="hdnEmail" id="hdnEmail" />     
</form>
```

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btnSubmit').click(function()
        {
          alert("hai");
            document.getElementById("getDetails").submit();
            document.getElementById("hdnName").value = $('#txtName').val();
            document.getElementById("hdnEmail").value = $('#txtEmail').val();
     });
    });  
 </script>
```

**Sub domain page - user.php**

```
<?php 
$act = formatstring($_POST['act']);
switch($act)
{
case "Users":
        $Name=$_POST['hdnName'];
        $Email=$_POST['hdnEmail'];  
        print($Name);
        exit();
}    
?>
```

In sub domain I am printing  the value but its not printing

Is it possible to submit a form from home domain to sub domain?

Comment: Short answer; yes, it's possible.

Comment: Then tell me how to solve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the action attribute of the form element from

```
http://customers.liyyas.com/
```

to

```
http://customers.liyyas.com/customers.php
```

I also assume you know that according to this code

```
$('#btnSubmit').click(function()
    {
      alert("hai");
        document.getElementById("getDetails").submit();
        document.getElementById("hdnName").value = $('#txtName').val();
        document.getElementById("hdnEmail").value = $('#txtEmail').val();
 });
```

The form will submit BEFORE the values of hdnName and hdnEmail are changed? That may also be a bug for you to quickly switch solve by switching around a few lines. The reason this may be a bug is that when your form submits the page will be reloaded meaning the user will never get to see the new values inserted via JavaScript.

The fix could be

```
$('#btnSubmit').click(function()
    {
      alert("hai");
        document.getElementById("hdnName").value = $('#txtName').val();
        document.getElementById("hdnEmail").value = $('#txtEmail').val();
        document.getElementById("getDetails").submit();
 });
```